# Accessing probabilities for PipeOps TwoClass Classif Learners

Tags: r, shiny, mlr3

I am currently working on [mlr3shiny](https://github.com/LamaTe/mlr3shiny). This program utilizes various mlr3 methods on an R shiny UI to make mlr3-models. I am currently unable to properly integrate the learner-objects to work with DALEX for model analysis. This problem arises **only for twoclass** models, as the pipeops turns the learners into `predict_type = "response"`. I cannot change this predict_type once it has been made, as I get the following error if I try to change it:

`PipeOpError: $predict_type for PipeOpThreshold is read-only.`

Due to these response-type learners, the learner does not put out probabilities I need for further analysis with DALEX

This is the function that is used to initialize the learner with twoclass learners being set to predict_type = 'response' as this is the default

```
createGraphLearner <- function(selectedlearner) {
  if (!isTRUE(currenttask$task$properties == "twoclass")) {
    learner <- lrn(input[[selectedlearner]]) 
  } else { # ...otherwise predict_type = "prob" is set and a threshold po added below
    learner <- lrn(input[[selectedlearner]], predict_type = "prob")
  }
  if(input[["Task_robustify"]]){
    graph <- pipeline_robustify(currenttask$task, learner) %>>% learner
  } else graph <- as_graph(po("learner", learner))
  plot(graph)  
  if (isTRUE(currenttask$task$properties == "twoclass")) graph <- graph %>>% po("threshold")
  
  return(as_learner(graph))
}
```

These learners can worked with in various ways, but I have not found a way to access the probabilities of the trained model once it has been trained on the final dataset.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Are you wondering why the predict type of a graphlearner is `response` if the final pipeop is a `PipeOpThreshold`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to get the probability prediction of a `GraphLearner`, whose final `PipeOP` is a `PipeOpThreshold`?

The answer might be unexpected.
Even though `PipeOpThreshold` claims to have the `predict_type` `"response"`, it actually outputs probabilities as well (this is a bug, that I reported [here](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3pipelines/issues/712)).

Fortunately for you this means that you don't have to change the learner's predict type, but still have access to the probabilities :)

Btw: Awesome that you are working on `mlr3shiny`! :) If you wanna get in touch you can join our mattermost channel that you can find on our website or on the README of the mlr-org on GitHub.

```r
library(mlr3verse)
#> Loading required package: mlr3

l = lrn("classif.rpart", predict_type = "prob")
task = tsk("sonar")

glrn = as_learner(
  po("learner", l) %>>%
    po("threshold"))

glrn$train(task)
glrn$predict_type
#> [1] "response"

p = glrn$predict(task)

p
#> <PredictionClassif> for 208 observations:
#>     row_ids truth response    prob.M    prob.R
#>           1     R        R 0.1060606 0.8939394
#>           2     R        M 0.7333333 0.2666667
#>           3     R        R 0.0000000 1.0000000
#> ---                                           
#>         206     M        M 0.9250000 0.0750000
#>         207     M        M 0.9250000 0.0750000
#>         208     M        M 0.9250000 0.0750000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Sebastian,

thank you for the answer (and I apologise for the delayed response). You were right, the probabilities were there. My problem lay in the truth and response columns and by transforming them into numeric columns with 1/0, DALEX accepted them :)